# Arduino does not work on battery

Tags: arduino-uno

The day before I got my used full package arduino uno. I tested it on USB plug. Everything worked fine. I wrote a piece of testing code and uploaded. After I have accomplished with the test I have unpluged arduino from PC and connected to battery and I see that it does not work. I have used a multi-tester to find out the voltage. It showed 4.7V. Now I wonder should I buy a new battery or there is another reason for this. Anybody, please suggest me what to do.
**Update**
The battery came with arduino set. It is written that it is a 9V battery. I am plugging it to the battery input in my arduino uno. Polarity is ok. The same program working on connection via usb, does not when connected to battery.

Comment: What kind of battery? How did you connect the battery to the Arduino? Did you check the polarity?

Comment: @EdgarBonet updated by question.

Comment: Do you read 4.7 V between "Vin" and "GND" or between "5V" and "GND"? Does the "ON" LED light up?

Comment: @EdgarBonet I think I got the point, the "ON" ligth has not turned on. So it means that the power supplied by battery is not enough to run the arduino?

Comment: What does your DMM say?

Comment: Do you have any other components plugged in anywhere, motors, leds etc?

Comment: Did you make sure the battery is charged? Does it have enough voltage to power the board? Remember that Arduino has internal voltage regulator, so you need something little more than 5V in order to get it working okay.

Comment: @bpinhosilva you are right, the battery was not supplying enough power to make arduino work.

Comment: @zazu I'm glad that it worked okay!

Comment: @bpinhosilva - If you made your comment an answer and expanded upon it a little, then the question could be marked as accepting an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Did you make sure the battery is charged? Does it have enough voltage to power the board? Remember that Arduino has internal voltage regulator, so you need something little more than 5V in order to get it working okay.

*(Comment by bpinhosilva re-purposed as an answer so this will stop showing up as unanswered).*

> @bpinhosilva you are right, the battery was not supplying enough power to make arduino work.

Please accept this so that the number of unanswered questions goes down. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the serial number of your board. Some boards were shipped with a defective boot loader, which has the loader stuck in an infinite loop when powered off and on again. Just Google the serial range of possible defective boards, and check if your board is in that range.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a battery that provides at least 7-12 volts. The voltage regulator will regulate the needed 5 volts for the arduino.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can weld a little electrolytic capacitor eg. 4 or 6 microfarads, 12 or more Volts, with the positive wire on the reset pin and the negative on the GND pin. in this way you can solve the restart without the USB connection.
This is what I did
Enjoy with Arduino.
By Daniele

Comment: This seems to address a different issue :)